# jquery mobile .clone collapsible menu -fiddle

Tags: jquery, events, mobile, clone

I have a page with a collapsible menu.
When the `$(document).width()` is below a specified menu I want to clone and append the whole menu to the header and offer a 'menu' link.

As the menu is pretty large I want to clone the already enriched html with it's click events.
Rather than building and enriching the menu a second time.

This works perfectly except for `ui-collapsibles` within the menu:

Please have a look:  (short code sample)
http://jsfiddle.net/N7Z9e/1478/

It doesn't matter which collapsible is clicked, the first one's expand/collapse function is called.

Investigating the `.data("events")` I can see they are sharing the same guid.
Does anyone know any hacks to work around this?

I am using `.clone(true)` - copying the registered event handlers because there are a lot of custom handlers coming from an mvc.

thanks alot!

Answer (score 0):

I think it's an issue with the jQuery Mobile implementation of the "mobile.collapsible" widget. If you check the code (http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.js) at line 4673, when the "expand collapse" event is bound to the collapsible widget (i.e. div#menu in your case), at line 4683, the collapsibleHeading object being toggled by the event is actually the collapsibleHeading of the original element being cloned; it is not the collapsibleHeading of the cloned element.

Comment: I reported this and the answer was:
Cloning already Enhanced Elements is not supported.